# Better alternatives for switch statements

Tags: c

I know that this has been already discussed, and there are multiple answers to it. See [Performance of array of functions over if and switch statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582261/performance-of-array-of-functions-over-if-and-switch-statements) for instance, however I would like to get some other ideas.

I've got a function with a large `switch` statement. This is 26 `case` and each with a "left" or "right" option. This function returns a pointer based on two given parameters (`plane` and `direction`):

```
double* getPointer(int plane, int direction) {
  switch (plane)
  {
  case 0:
    if (direction == 0)
      return  p_YZ_L; // Left
    else if (dir == 1)
      return p_YZ_R;  //Right
    else {
      return 0;
    }

    break;
    ...
  case 25:
    ...
  }
}
```

with

```
planes -> [0-25]
direction -> [0,1]
```

I have been thinking on an array of functions, but this could also be tedious and I am not sure if it is the best option. Also it is not clear to me how to do it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the code containing the`switch` statements you are talking about.

Comment: Two functions with 26 switch cases may be a good alternative, assuming that right and left sub-cases do not share much code.

Comment: How about array `double* x[2][26]` and `return x[direction][plane]`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz This shows only one large `switch` with `if else` within each `case`

Comment: Maybe a table with 26 entries ?

Comment: @_Kerrek  @MichaelWalz Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Manolete see my answer, Maybe you should elaborate your sample and add just the code for `case 1:` as well.

Comment: I'm a bit late on this but rather than use arrays of double, why not use an unsigned 32 bit integer with flags.  Wherein bit 0 is the direction and bits 1-26 indicate the plane(s) using flags.  I say planes because it would enable formation movement ~0 (all move right) and ~1 (all move left)... you could also reserve extra bits for up/down (or pitch, yaw and roll to be more appropriate).

Comment: @technosaurus I know it's late, but if you could elaborate your answer would be great for the community!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a lookup table like this:

```
double *pointers[26][2] = {
    { p_YZ_L, p_YZ_R },
    ...
};
```

Then your function becomes much simpler:

```
double* getPointer(int plane, int direction) {
    if ((plane >= 0) && (plane < 26) && (direction >= 0) && (direction < 2)) {
        return pointers[plane][direction];
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: @_dbush Shouldn't this be `direction < 2` ?

Comment: @Manolete Yes it should.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just tired of typing, yu can use the preprocessor, e.g.:

```
#define PLZ(dir) if(!dir)return(p_YZ_L);else if(dir==1)return(p_YZ_R);else return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure, but maybe you want this:

```
struct
{
  double dir[2];
} directions[26] =
{
  { p_YZ_L, p_YZ_R},
  { ..., ... },           // 25 pairs of options here
  ...            
};

double* getPointer(int plane, int direction) {
  return  &directions[plane].dir[direction];
}
```

More tests need to be added to be sure that `plane` and `direction` are within required bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while with an iterator as follows:

```
double* getPointer(int plane, int direction){
  int i=0;
  while (i<26){
    if (plane == i){
       if (direction == 0)
          return  p_YZ_L; //Left
       else if(dir==1)
          return p_YZ_R; //Right
       else 
          return 0;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

It is not optimized but it is less code with respect to your version.

Comment: @_reshad I agree, it's less code but not what I am after